# parse the fragment and find all top level definitions

Tags: go

The service I'm writing receive code snippets and process them, the snippets could either be complement program or a fragment, if it is a fragment, I need to add the enclosing `main` function. For example, the snippet:

```
var v int
v = 3
fmt.Println(v)
```

should be classified as a fragment, and add `main` to it:

```
func main() {
    var v int
    v = 3
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

If the snippet is:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

then no modification should be done.

The way I'm doing now is run the go parser against the snippet:

```
var fset *token.FileSet
file, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "stdin", code, 0)
if err != nil {
        // add function
        code = fmt.Sprintf("func main() {\n%s\n}", code)
        // ...
}
```

This works for the 1st snippet above, however it fails if the fragment has a `main` function after some other declarations, e.g.

```
type S struct {
    a int
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

I also try to look into the `file` returned by `ParseFile`, check the `Decls`, but it looks it will stop parsing after the 1st error, so `Decls` is `nil` in this case. So my question is is there a robust way to handle this?

PS. The inclusion of package clause and the required imports are not relevant because I'm feeding the processed code into `golang.org/x/tools/imports` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The dumbest thing that might work is after reading in the file (to a buffer most likely), is to do a string search for `func main(){`.

If it isn't formatted already, you might need to change that to a regex with whitespaces, but it should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: grep the source would be really last resort, I'm searching for a more elegant solution.